# VSTO 2010 Outlook Ribbon (Designer) does not show up in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, ribbon

I have a VSTO 2010 Ribbon (Designer) which works in Outlook 2010.
My add-in also loads in Outlook 2007, I see a command bar that I have made and it does what I expect it to. For some reason the ribbons on the Read mail and New mail inspectors do not show up in Outlook 2007.

What am I missing that would prevent these from loading? From what I understand, as long as the Tab names match the ribbon controls file tab names in both 2007 and 2010 it should be fine?

Notes:

- The add-in is for sure loading in outlook 2007
- Works perfect in outlook 2010
- Not talking about the ribbon in the main UI
- I would prefer to just have the ribbon files like for outlook 2010 but I can do whatever as long as it works
- If there is a duplicate question which solves my issue that would be great but I can't seem to find one that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know developing for multiple Office versions with VSTO can be a pain and is not directly supported by VSTO:

> This of course is the advantage of using the old "shared add-in"
>   project types – you can build one add-in that targets all versions of
>   all Office apps that support COM add-ins (ie, 2000 onwards). The
>   question is, can you do something similar with VSTO add-ins? The
>   answer is "No, not in any supported way".

The answer can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/06/15/can-you-build-one-add-in-for-multiple-versions-of-office.aspx

There are alternatives to VSTO for Office development, that help you develop for multiple versions: [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/), [Addin Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/).

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen NetOffice before, I may check it out.